# Error in CAN reception

Tags: can

If one node is transmitting a message to more than one node and if one of the receiver node failed to receive the message, then how does the transmitter node know which node has failed to receive the message?

Comment: It doesn't know which node that has failed, because very likely the fault is not with the receiver, but with the transmitter or the bus itself. So typically, if one node fails, all nodes fail.

Answer (score 2):

When one of the CAN nodes detects an error, it issues an [error frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Error_frame).
This is a frame that starts with *at least* 6 dominant bits, which is violates the [bit stuffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN_bus#Bit_stuffing) rule.

The dominant bit does what it's named after. Inhibiting all other traffic of the bus until the frame is cleared. Interrupting the currently transmitting node, which could then start transmitting again after bus arbitration.
Depending on the NART (no automatic re-transmit) setting of course.

Also, CAN always transmits to all nodes. There is no addressing.
The identifier describes the *content* of the message.
The transmitter also does not know which node issued the error frame.

Comment: Re *... it issues an error frame*: which causes the rest of the nodes to do the same

Comment: who send the error frame on bus.

Comment: mens there is now way to know which node has problem..

Comment: @SHRIRAJSHIGWAN Any node who detects the error first. You don't know which node.

Answer (score 2):

On the face of it a CAN bus ACK can only ever indicate that at least one receiver received a good message frame. Good frame reception is indicated by overwriting a recessive bit with a dominant bit and, for a receiver not getting good data, its natural recessive bit is more than likely overwritten by those receivers that receive a good message.

So, the way this can be done is by generating an error frame - it consists of 6 dominant bits and 6 in a row violates the bit stuffing rule for normal transmissions. This method ensures that a broken receive message can be almost immediately detected by the original sender or any other receiver.

Of course if the payload data was deemed to be in error then that receiver can wait until it has bus access and transmit a higher level message that the original sender will interpret as indicating a message problem.

Comment: please explain 2nd para in detail....

Comment: Any receiver, if it wants to flag an important error situation can disrupt the whole CAN bus by forcing 6 dominant bits on the bus. This will break the bit-stuffing rule and indicate an error. [Here's](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn0obhmIrcAhXMe8AKHUj5Bf4QFghtMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fan%2Fsloa101b%2Fsloa101b.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3WBIOH4in21IvIftR6A2S4) a great document by TI that explains in more detail.